# trying to catch hover on tt-suggestion

Tags: jquery, css, typeahead.js, bloodhound

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Input</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Type few letters"  autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

and the code

```
$('.tt-suggestion').on('mouseover', function(){
    // verify input
    console.log('got it');
});
```

I'm not able to catch mouse hovering on typeahead's suggestions.

typeahead:cursorchanged works only for keyboard selection 
while .on('hover') just ignores the movement.

Any suggestions? (not tt ones :D)

so be it - manemoi
Theodore

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understand your question, you could use this syntax instead:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.tt-suggestion', function(){
        console.log("got it");
    });
```

Comment: What's the difference between his and yours function. Can't figure out why his doesn't work.